# MVC Localization ViewData["message"]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If i wanted to get message for ViewData from resource file, depending on the culture i set, how can i do this?

ViewData["message"] = "ErrorMessage";

am i making sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewData["message"] = Resources.ErrorMessage;
```

where `Resources` is a resx file that you've added to your project. Visual Studio automatically generates strongly typed classes for each resource you add.